# Как выводить только отзывы в табах woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Как сделать так что бы выводило только отзывы без дополнительной информации?

```
<div class="woocommerce-product__tabs woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper tabs">
        <div class="woocommerce-product__tabs-links">
            <div class="woocommerce-product__tab product-tab__active">1</div>
            <div class="woocommerce-product__tab">2</div>
            <div class="woocommerce-product__tab">3</div>
            <div class="woocommerce-product__tab">4</div>
            <div class="woocommerce-product__tab">5</div>
        </div>
        <div class="woocommerce-product__tabs-wrapper">
            <div class="woocommerce-product__tab-item"><?php the_field( 'characteristics' ); ?></div>
            <div class="woocommerce-product__tab-item"><?php the_field( 'complete_set' ); ?></div>
            <div class="woocommerce-product__tab-item"><?php the_field( 'review' ); ?></div>
            <div class="woocommerce-product__tab-item"><?php the_field( 'recipes' ); ?></div>
            <?php foreach ( $product_tabs as $key => $product_tab ) : ?>
                <div class="woocommerce-product__tab-item woocommerce-Tabs-panel woocommerce-Tabs-panel--<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?> panel entry-content wc-tab" id="tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-title-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>">
                    <?php
                    if ( isset( $product_tab['callback'] ) ) {
                        call_user_func( $product_tab['callback'], $key, $product_tab );
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_tabs' ); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: 1. Что это за код? Где он, в дочерней теме или в основной? 2. Покажите на картинке, что для вас значит "дополнительная информация".

Answer (score 0):

1. копируешь из вукоммерс шаблоны в свою папку шаблона и в файле комментария, удаляешь что не надо.
2. если удаляется не всё, смотришь хуки, что за это отвечают и там отрубаешь.

Путь к шаблону отзывов

1. \wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\single-product\review.php
2. \wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\single-product\review-meta.php
3. \wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\single-product\review-rating.php

**!!!ИХ НАДО ПЕРЕНЕСТИ К СЕБЕ В ДОЧЕРНЮЮ ТЕМУ!!!**

Хуки надо смотреть что именно тебе надо и что есть.
Самое просто, это подкорректировать файлы шаблонов у себя в дочерней теме.

Но помни, при обновлении WooCommerce или Шаблона, вероятно придётся обновлять шаблоны у себя в папке.